# sh: 1: /home/spark-1.4.1/bin/spark-submit: not found Error in sparkR.init(master = "local") : JVM is not ready after 10 seconds

Tags: r, ubuntu, apache-spark

I'm trying to execute SparkR on Ubuntu. I used following code

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/home/spark-1.4.1")

.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"), .libPaths()))

library("SparkR", lib.loc="/usr/local/src/spark/spark-1.4.1/R/lib") # The use of \\ is fof windows environment.

library(SparkR)

sc=sparkR.init(master="local")
```

But after executing the code I'm getting following error message

```
sh: 1: /home/spark-1.4.1/bin/spark-submit: not found
Error in sparkR.init(master = "local") : 
JVM is not ready after 10 seconds
```

I found several stackoverflow post on similar problem, but all of those were on Windows platform.

My system settings are

- Ubuntu 16.0
- Scala 2.11.6
- Spark 1.4.1
- R Studio 1.0.143
- R 3.2.3